# Text from Code Code Behind into Textblock with Different Font Style

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface, styles

I have a text block whose text is generated by a converter from a bound object. I am trying to have only part of the text in a different font than the rest. Is this possible in Silverlight/WPF?

How would I go about generating code to produce this effect?

Example Text:

-Hello, this is some text- "More text"

Where any text in -- is one font, and "" denotes another font.
I looked into inline runs, but that did not seem feasible with code behind.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct to do Inlines

```
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run
                           {
                               FontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans"),
                               Text = "Your text"
                           });
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run
        {
            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma"),
            Text = " is different"
        });
```

One possible other solution if you already know what the text will be (you know that there will be two portions of text) is to have some pre-canned xaml ready to go and use the XamlReader.Parse method

Comment: The text is being generated in the converter, so I do not know what object it is going to. Is there a way to give text to the textbox and have some style apply the font formatting?

Comment: Instead of putting a TextBlock in your xaml, put a ContentControl/ContentPresenter. and Bind the Content to your value converter. Your value converter would return a TextBlock with the Inlines in it.